# Magento - Set Order as Complete for Free Downloable Product

Tags: magento

I searched a lot on this website but couldn't find a specific answer for my problem so here i go, thanks in advance.

I have Store Credit and Coupons working on my Store, with Credit Card. Store credit is working fine, also the coupons but i cannot make those purchases to be ser as COMPLETE. They stay in "Pending" and i need it as Complete so the download will be enable. If downloadble product is in Pending, then you cannot download.

The place where i worked a lot is on app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Free.php

I checked on this file and at the bottom i have:

```
/**
     * Get config payment action, do nothing if status is pending
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getConfigPaymentAction()
    {
        return $this->getConfigData('order_status') == 'pending' ? null :     parent::getConfigPaymentAction();
    }
```

It's saying: "If pending, do nothing"...and what i want if it's pending, change it as Complete.

Also i'm using Zero Subtotal Checkout and it's setup as "Complete" th status but seems that's not working or something is overriding this.

Answer (score 1):

By default, users can only download when the invoice is made(order complete). You can, however, change this setting so that users can download products on pending orders.

Here's how to do it:

Go to System->Configuration->Catalog->Downloadable Product Options and change the value for Order Item Status to Enable Download to Pending.

Comment: Thank you, Nitin. The problem with that approach is that i have two payments methods: Credit Card or Store Credit that they already have. If i put that they can download files on "pending", they'll be able to download even if the payment wasn't done and i don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Soledad, There are two approaches to this issue. Firstly, set up the status for downloadable products correctly and use Zero Checkout Payment Method. Secondly, if the first one is not working, add manually the status. I've written an article about it at [my blog](http://blog.mdnsolutions.com/index.php/magento-free-order-with-status-as-complete/). I hope it helps.